# Where to find bitnami MAMPStack v.8.1 7 last iteration?

Tags: mysql

Did anyone keep or do know where to find Bitnami MAMPStack v.8.1.7, their last iteration of MAMPStack  before discontinuing it?
MAMP has not been updated to MySQL 8.x yet and it's a working alternative.

TKS in advance.

I can't find it at the moment.